# bind('contextmenu') not working for ios

Tags: javascript, ios, events, safari

I want to catch long touch on mobiles, I wrote

```
$('.myObject').bind('contextmenu', function(e){ ... my code ... });
```

it works on all devices, except ios Safari, do anyone knows what is problem and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using jQuery mobiles *taphold* event instead? It's literally meant for this. So instead of writing:

```
$('.myObject').bind('contextmenu', function(e){ ... my code ... });
```

You would write:

```
jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "taphold", function(e) { ... your code ... })
```

If you go this route, don't forget to include jQuery mobile!

[Further reading here.](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/)

Comment: it's not little site, I'm working on big application and we aren't using jquery mobile, so I cant add jquery mobile only for catching long tap

Comment: I'm not sure how the size of the site is overly relevant to the usage of jQuery mobile. How big are we talking here? Are you using Cordova? If it's just a site, large or not, it *shouldn't* add more than 200ms to your page load, at most. You can use both jQuery *and* jQuery Mobile without any issue. You literally only need to add the jQuery Mobile src of your choosing to wherever you are loading your scripts, and then you are free to use the *taphold* feature. If you really wanted to, you could use js `mouseup` , `mousedown` and timer methods to do this, but it can cause unwanted behaviour.